# ¿Cómo insertar datos después de 48 horas?

Tags: php, mysqli

Mi sistema está registrando datos seguidamente sin control desde la misma `ip`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esa `ip` no vuelva registrar datos, al menos que hayan pasado 48 horas para que se vuelva registrar nuevamente?

Entiendo que desde una consulta previa, se debe obtener el ultimo dato insertado:

`SELECT visitor_ip FROM visitors_table ORDER BY visitor_date DESC LIMIT 1`

Pero como lo valido, si aún no paso las 48 horas que no inserta datos y si ya paso las 48 horas que se vuelvan a registrar sus datos.

```
<?php
require_once('visitors_connections.php');

$visitor_ip = GetIP();
$visitor_browser = getBrowserType($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$visitor_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$visitor_refferer = $refferer;
$visited_page = selfURL();


$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO visitors_table (visitor_ip, visitor_browser, visitor_date,
 visitor_refferer, visitor_page) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $visitor_ip,$visitor_browser,$visitor_date,$visitor_refferer,$visited_page);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Mi tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: visitante = misma IP y navegador ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes hacer la consulta si existe limitando las fechas a las últimas 48 horas, por ejemplo :

```
SELECT visitor_ip, visitor_date
  FROM visitors_table 
  WHERE visitor_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
    AND visitor_ip = "290.118.71.19"
  ORDER BY visitor_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Tener en cuenta que una misma IP puede tener varios dispositivos conectados (routers) así que sería mas conveniente filtrar también por user agent o visitor_browser

```
SELECT visitor_ip, visitor_date
  FROM visitors_table 
  WHERE visitor_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
    AND visitor_ip = "290.118.71.19"
    AND visitor_browser = "Chrome"
  ORDER BY visitor_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Eso contaría las visitas de un chrome pero no de un ipad por ejemplo.
Si esta consulta no da resultados, procedes a hacer el insert.

Nota al margen, las IP conviene guardarlas en un varchar de al menos 45 letras para que soporte las IPv6

```
 `visitor_ip` varchar(45)
```

por ejemplo el externalhit de facebook que genera las miniaturas y el resumen de un enlace compartido en la red social se vería algo así (IP, fecha, UserAgent):

```
'2a03:2880:11:8ff4:face:b00c:0:8000', 
'2018-08-09 20:31:48', 
'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
```

También otro user agent que podría ser engañoso es el de CloudFlare

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CloudFlare-AlwaysOnline/1.0; +http://www.cloudflare.com/always-online) AppleWebKit/534.34'
```

Todo junto quedaría :

```
<?php
require_once('visitors_connections.php');

$visitor_ip = GetIP();
$visitor_browser = getBrowserType($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$visitor_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$visitor_refferer = $refferer;
$visited_page = selfURL();

$stmt = $con->prepare(
 "SELECT visitor_ip, visitor_date
  FROM visitors_table 
  WHERE visitor_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
    AND visitor_ip = ?
  ORDER BY visitor_date DESC
  LIMIT 1;
");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$visitor_ip);
$stmt->execute() or die();
$stmt->store_result();
$no_hay_registros = ($stmt->num_rows==0);

if ($no_hay_registros) {
   // Si no hay registros para esa IP en las últimas 48 horas    
  $stmt = $con->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO visitors_table 
        (visitor_ip, visitor_browser, visitor_date, visitor_refferer, visitor_page) 
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sssss",
      $visitor_ip,
      $visitor_browser,
      $visitor_date,
      $visitor_refferer,
      $visited_page
  );
  $stmt->execute();
} else {
  // ya hay un registro en las últimas 48 horas
}
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo, de esta forma, solo es necesario desde mi consulta que inserta datos o igual se necesitan dos.

Comment: son dos consultas, con la primera traes registros de las ultimas 48 horas. con la segunda insertas sólo si la primera no trajo datos. lo necesitas en php?

Comment: Pero como inserto los datos de la `ip`?

Comment: ahi te lo pongo según tu codigo php

Comment: la respuesta de IniDesing.com me indica como, pero ese ejemplo no funciona.

Comment: porque si no tiene registro en la base datos muestra el mensaje la fecha no es igual, ese ejemplo solo funciona cuando existen registro.

Comment: solo es necesario por `ip` no por navegador, porque ese usuario puede tener varios, solo con la `ip`

Answer (score 1):

entiendo intentalo asi:

```
//en la consulta debes traer el campo `visitor_date` para comprar
SELECT visitor_ip, visitor_date FROM visitors_table ORDER BY visitor_date DESC LIMIT 1

// al campo que traes le sumas 2 dias que representan las 48 horas que necesitas
$fecha_registro= date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(visitor_date."+ 2 days"));

//creas la fecha actual
$fecha_hoy = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//comparas si es mayor o igual
if (($fecha_registro >= $fecha_hoy) {
    //ejecute la funcion
}
```

Te dejo el [Link donde quizas te ayudes un poco mas a entender](https://www.anerbarrena.com/sumar-restar-fechas-php-5655/)

Espero te sirva y la marques xD... ReNiceCode...

Answer (score 1):

si te basas en la visita de un usuario puedes hacer un select primero para ver cual es el utlimo campo registrado por ejemplo

```
SELECT visitor_date FROM visitors_table WHERE  ORDER BY visitor_date DESC limit 1
```

y el resultado guardarlo en una variable de PHP

después compararla con la actual

```
$fechaRow = new DateTime($resultadoQuery);
$fechaCliente = new DateTime();

$diferencia = $fechaRow->diff($fechaCliente);

$horas = $diferencia->format('%H');

if((int)$horas > 48 ){

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO visitors_table (visitor_ip, visitor_browser, visitor_date,
 visitor_refferer, visitor_page) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $visitor_ip,$visitor_browser,$visitor_date,$visitor_refferer,$visited_page);
$stmt->execute();

}
```

espero que te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 1):

Registrar la misma `ip` después de `48hrs` que es igual a `2 días`.

Para ello podemos jugar mediante `presente` y `futuro`.

Ejemplos:

```
$hoy = "2018-08-12 13:34:08";
$futuro = "2018-08-12 13:34:08";
```

Luego realizas la comprobación mediante un `if`

```
// == >= <=
if ($hoy >= $futuro) {
    //Aquí agregas la ejecución de la consulta.
    echo "la fecha es igual o mayor";
} else {
    echo "La fecha no es igual";
}
```

Una ves teniendo la idea en mente puedes realizar el siguiente procedimiento:

```
$stmtIP = $con->prepare("SELECT visitor_ip, visitor_date FROM visitors_table WHERE visitor_ip=? ORDER BY visitor_date DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmtIP->bind_param("s",$visitor_ip);
$stmtIP->execute();
$stmtIP->store_result();
$stmtIP->bind_result($publishers_ip, $publishers_date);
//$stmtIP->fetch();

if ($stmtIP -> fetch()){
  $date_day = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $publishers_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 days'));
} else {
  //echo "0 registros";
}

if ($date_day >= $publishers_date) {
    //Aquí agregas la ejecución de la consulta.
    echo "la fecha es igual o mayor";
} else {
    echo "La fecha no es igual";
}
```

Comment: Ahora si me registra datos cuando no existe registro en la tabla de datos, antes no me registraba.